# How performant is frequent addition to a set in Cassandra?

Tags: performance, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, insert-update, database-locking

I am trying to add values to a set (A Cassandra collection) frequently.
I have a schema design such as,

frequent_access_data(
type text,
values set
);

Now in my each store operation (which is at faster rate, say 10000 records per second), I am executing following update statement.

**update frequent_access_data set values = values + :new_value where type='TYPE1'"**

So in that statement, sometimes the new_value would already be present in values collection while sometimes it won't. So I am running the update blindly. How efficient it would be ?

Will "if" clause make any difference ? If yes, how can I leverage that ?

I have also read, Cassandra doesn't lock the row for update. Is that true ? 
Because RDBMS locks it and makes the update slower.